# Sending a Request Message through WCF stack

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

We have a WCF Service (ServiceContact + Implementation class). The service was originally self hosted using ServiceHost and BasicHttpBinding using TransportWithMessageCredential.

Clients have been configured to use this service and cannot be changed except to be pointed to a new url.

Now we want to change how the service is hosted. The entry point on the new host (not IIS) is an Http request message (headers and body). The idea is that we point clients to the new host and bridge the gap between the Http request and the WCF Stack.

In theory it sounds like we have to create a new TransportBindingElement, followed by a CustomBinding to use this transport. This is proving mind bogglingly complicated.

Alternatively, what sounds easier is, if possible, to create a WCF Message instance from the http request, and somehow send it through the various existing binding elements used by BasicHttpBinding (mainly so all the Security headers are processed), and somehow end up in our WCF Service implementation.

Does anyone have any idea on if and how this may be possible?

2019-06-14: Adding sample to demonstrate challenge:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string Invert(string s);
    }

    public interface IServiceChannel : IService, IClientChannel
    {
    }

    public class Service : IService
    {
        public string Invert(string s)
        {
            char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();
            Array.Reverse(charArray);
            return new string(charArray);
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (a, b, c, d) => true;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 for WCF Listene, anything else for HttpListener");
            var option = Console.ReadLine();

            if(option == "1")
            {
                Task.Run(() => StartWCFHost());
            }
            else
            {
                Task.Run(() => StartHttpListenerHost());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("hosting");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter string to invert");
            var streingToInvert = Console.ReadLine();
            var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
            var cf = new ChannelFactory<IService>(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://localhost:20443/myservice"));
            cf.Credentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "dc72486676c5e983589897fca5051a360376777d");

            var client = cf.CreateChannel();
            try
            {
                var r = client.Invert(streingToInvert);
                Console.WriteLine(r);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        private static void StartHttpListenerHost()
        {
            var web = new HttpListener();
            web.Prefixes.Add("https://localhost:20443/");
            Console.WriteLine("Listening..");
            web.Start();
            while(true)
            {
                var context = web.GetContext();
                var soapMessage = Message.CreateMessage(XmlReader.Create(context.Request.InputStream), int.MaxValue, MessageVersion.Soap11);

                //TODO: How do we process request security related headers and give a proper response to client?
                //Ideally we want to use Service implementation class and WCF Bindings/BindingElements to process headers and generate response message
                //For the time being just read body write it to console

                var body = soapMessage.GetReaderAtBodyContents().ReadOuterXml();

                Console.WriteLine(soapMessage.ToString());

                Console.WriteLine(body);

                context.Response.Close();
            }
        }

        private static void StartWCFHost()
        {
            ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("https://localhost:20443/myservice"));
            var binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();
            binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpsSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
            var se = sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), binding, "https://localhost:20443/myservice");
            sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(new ServiceMetadataBehavior { HttpsGetEnabled = true });
            sh.Credentials.ServiceCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "dc72486676c5e983589897fca5051a360376777d");
            sh.Credentials.ClientCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
            sh.Open();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a highly specific scenario, I have manipulated apps in similar ways, routing old WCF clients over to OData, and other REST conventions. Each time has been sadly different, it largely depends on the original WCF implementation. Include an example request that you want to support and the C# that you have tried to implement to receive that request. Sometimes it can be as simple as web.config changes, other times we have to write a message handler to intercept, that then gets registered into web.config.

Comment: Why not replace your original service with a dummy proxy WCF (that has the exact same contract as before and hosted in the same spot) that simply invokes your real new service using whatever protocol you wish.  This is the essence of [API Management](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/)

Comment: @ChrisSchaller - I added a sample to demonstrate the challenge